# Exported Database Dumpfile Incorrect

Tags: php, mysql, dump

I'm trying to create a page with a button when clicked will download the database named `sampledb`.

Here's my `backup.php`

```
<?php
ob_start();

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbname   = "sampledb";

$command = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.24\\bin\\mysqldump --add-drop-table --host=" . $hostname . "--user=". $username ." --password=". $password." ".$dbname;
system($command);

$dump = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// send dump file to the output
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=sqlfile.sql');
readfile('sqlfile.sql');
flush();
echo $dump;
exit();
?>
```

The export was successful. However, when I checked the downloaded file (sqlfile.sql) in the downloads folder, its file size is only 2kB. I tried exporting the `sampledb` using phpMyAdmin and found out the actual file size is 9kB.

Moreover, when I tried importing the `sqlfile.sql` through phpMyAdmin, I got an error message. It says `Warning: readfile(sqlfile.sql)`.

Something is wrong with my export code. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 20131205**

I tried appending `> sqlfile.sql` to this part of my code.

`$command = "C:\\wamp\\bin\\mysql\\mysql5.5.24\\bin\\mysqldump. --add-drop-table --host=" . $hostname . "--user=". $username ." --password=". $password." ".$dbname;`

File size is still incorrect. I cannot upload the downloaded file to phpMyAdmin.

**END UPDATE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqldump` needs to be dumped into a file, otherwise it just returns the results as text.

Usually this is done by redirecting into a file:

```
mysqldump --... > dump.sql
```